# SQL Scripting For Sub-Novice

Tags: mysql, sql

Today is a big day for me: I've installed MySQL on my server, created my first database, my first table, run my first queries, imported my first .txt as a table. Now I'm stuck.

OK so I've learned to use LOAD DATA INFILE...

I have thousands of file in a folder I'd like to run this same command on. How do I do this?

Comment: Well, how do you know what the name of the produced tables will be? What about the columns and their datatypes?

Comment: If you installed SQL Server why is this question tagged as mysql?, wich one is it?

Comment: I mean generally. Once I get some sort of information on how to script this I would likely just name the table the same as the text file minus the extension.

Comment: And if it is SQL Server then you should use integration services for this (hint: take a look at the `For Each Loop`)

Comment: I'm familiar with FOR EACH WHILE etc. etc. etc. If this were JavaScript I could do it without a problem. How do I do this in mySQL

Comment: LOL like what is the batch file equivalent in SQL?

Answer (score -1):

I need a bit more information in order to help.

1. You used the term 'SQL Server' that is usually in reference to Microsoft's SQL Server but your question is tagged as mysql.  Which of the two are you using?
2. Is the format of your files different?  Would they all load to the same table?
3. What operating system are you using (comfortable with)?

If you are using MySQL on linux then just use cat to combine all of your files into one large file and load that one.

Comment: I'm using MySQL server. 
All of the files would load to the same server, however their separateness is is precisely why I'm looking for a database. My hope is to be able to compare the files to one another, if they are concatenated I won't be able to do so. 
Finally I am most comfortable with using Windows.

I guess the core of my question, very poorly stated, is whether or not MySQL supports scripting and if so what language? I'm starting to think that maybe I'm supposed to do something like write a script in Python that integrates with the server?